# Using purrr::possibly to catch dynamic error messages

Tags: r, purrr, function-parameter

I've written a custom function that does a number of checks and throws a different error when a check fails.
Below is a simple example function that takes a data.frame and a column name and simply outputs the sum of that column. I'm using purrr::possibly() to create a saver version of that function so that I can loop over a vector of column names.

```
foo <- function(df, var){     

  #check 1  
if(var %in% names(df) == FALSE){
    stop(paste0("No column with name ", var, " found."))}  

  #check 2
if(all(is.na(dplyr::select(df, {{var}})))) {
   stop(paste0("All values of column ", var, " are missing."))}
  
  # main function  
  result <- df %>% 
    dplyr::rename(var = {{var}}) %>%
    dplyr::summarise(sum = sum(var))

#print(result) printing shows the correct error messages   
}

safer_foo <- purrr::possibly(.f = foo, otherwise = "error", quiet = FALSE)
```

I use purrr::map to loop over a vector of columns and store the output in a list. However, for elements where the function fails, I would like to store the specific error message instead of the static input of the "otherwise" argument of purrr::possibly requires.
Replacing purrr::possibly with purrr::safely actually captures the specific error message as intended in the $error element of the list but I would like to avoid the extra nested level that safely creates.

```
test_df <- tibble(A = 1:10, C = NA)
input <- c("A", "B", "C")

output_list <- map(input, ~safer_foo(test_df, .x)) %>% set_names(input)
```

Output

```
> output_list

    sum
  <int>
1    55

$B
[1] "error"

$C
[1] "error"
```

Desired output

```
> output_list

    sum
  <int>
$A   55

$B
[1] "Error: No column with name B found."

$C
[1] "Error: All values of column C are missing."
```

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using `stop` in your `foo` function and return the error string directly

Comment: Do you suggest this because in the case of this example the errors would be fairly clear and stop() is not really necessary? Or is there any negative behavior that stop( ) could introduce if used inside a function? The reason I've opted for the use of stop() was that in my real (more complex) function, I want to execute a number of different checks for the most common problem causes before the main part of the function is even executed. If any of them fails the user should receive a more understandable error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could tweak `purrr::possibly()` from its original code to *return* instead of *message* the error.

Original code:

```
## > possibly
## function (.f, otherwise, quiet = TRUE) 
## {
##     .f <- as_mapper(.f)
##     force(otherwise)
##     function(...) {
##         tryCatch(.f(...), error = function(e) {
##             if (!quiet) 
##                 message("Error: ", e$message) ## <--- tweak
##             otherwise
##         }, interrupt = function(e) {
##             stop("Terminated by user", call. = FALSE)
##         })
##     }
## }
```

tweaked function:

```
possibly2 <- function (.f, otherwise, quiet = TRUE) {
    .f <- as_mapper(.f)
    force(otherwise)
    function(...) {
        tryCatch(.f(...), error = function(e) {
            if (!quiet) 
                return(e$message) ## <-- tweaked
            otherwise
        }, interrupt = function(e) {
            stop("Terminated by user", call. = FALSE)
        })
    }
}
```

Example:

```
safer_foo <- possibly2(.f = foo, otherwise = "error",
                       quiet = FALSE ## don't forget to "unquiet"
                       )

## all other objects / code as in your example
```

Output:

```
## > output_list
## $A
## # A tibble: 1 x 1
##     sum
##   <int>
## 1    55
## 
## $B
## [1] "No column with name B found."
## 
## $C
## [1] "All values of column C are missing."
```

**edit**

Actually, `possibly2` carries over code which is no longer needed. Omitting
the unwanted static arguments `otherwise` and `quiet`, and skipping the handler for user interrupts, the required code shrinks down to:

```
possibly2 <- function (.f) {
    .f <- as_mapper(.f)
    function(...) {
        tryCatch(.f(...), error = function(e)  e$message)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works as intended.

I see that object "e" is created inside of the tryCatch( ) function that purrr::possibly calls. But I wonder where the $message part comes from. Where exactly is that message element attached to "e"? Also, if I e.g. wanted to capture warnings instead of errors, I would add the warning = function(w){return(w$message)} argument to tryCatch? Or would that work differently?

Comment: The error (a list of class "error") is produced by the instruction that raises the error. It has a list member "message" which you access with `some_error_object$message`. Similar with warning, as you already guessed. You can generate error or warning objects with `simpleError(...)` and `simpleWarning()` and inspect their structure like `simpleWarning(message = "look out!") %>% str`